# Pandas concatenate/join/group rows in a dataframe based on date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataset like this:

```
                Date      WaterTemp   Discharge AirTemp        Precip  
0       2012-10-05 00:00       10.9      414.0    39.2           0.0   
1       2012-10-05 00:15       10.1      406.0    39.2           0.0   
2       2012-10-05 00:45       10.4      406.0    37.4           0.0   
...
63661   2016-10-12 14:30       10.5      329.0    15.8           0.0   
63662   2016-10-12 14:45       10.6      323.0    19.4           0.0   
63663   2016-10-12 15:15       10.8      329.0      23           0.0
```

I want to extend each row so that I get a dataset that looks like:

```
              Date    WaterTemp 00:00    WaterTemp 00:15 .... Discharge 00:00 ...
0       2012-10-05                10.9              10.1                414.0
```

There will be at most 72 readings for each date so I should have 288 columns in addition to the date and index columns, and at most I should have at most 1460 rows (4 years * 365 days in year - possibly some missing dates). Eventually, I will use the 288-column dataset in a classification task (I'll be adding the label later), so I need to convert this dataframe to a 2d array (sans datetime) to feed into the classifier, so I can't simply group by date and then access the group. I did try grouping based on date, but I was uncertain how to change each group into a single row. I also looked at joining. It looks like joining could suit my needs (for example a join based on (day, month, year)) but I was uncertain how to split things into different pandas dataframes so that the join would work. What is a way to do this?

PS. I do already know how to change the my datetimes in my Date column to dates without the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I group the readings by time of day of reading. Each group is a dataframe in and of itself, so I just then need to concatenate the dataframes based on date. My code for the whole function is as follows.

```
import pandas

def readInData(filename):
    #read in files and remove missing values
    ds = pandas.read_csv(filename) 
    ds = ds[ds.AirTemp != 'M']
    #set index to date
    ds['Date'] = pandas.to_datetime(ds.Date, yearfirst=True, errors='coerce')
    ds.Date = pandas.DatetimeIndex(ds.Date)
    ds.index = ds.Date
    #group by time (so group readings by time of day of reading, i.e. all readings at midnight)
    dg = ds.groupby(ds.index.time)

    #initialize the final dataframe
    df = pandas.DataFrame()
    for name, group in dg: #for each group
        #each group is a dateframe
        try:
            #set unique column names except for date
            group.columns = ['Date', 'WaterTemp'+str(name), 'Discharge'+str(name), 'AirTemp'+str(name), 'Precip'+str(name)]
            #ensure date is the index            
            group.index = group.Date
            #remove time from index
            group.index = group.index.normalize()
            #join based on date
            df = pandas.concat([df, group], axis=1)
        except: #if the try catch block isn't here, throws errors! (three for my dataset?)
            pass
    #remove duplicate date columns
    df = df.loc[:,~df.columns.duplicated()]
    #since date is index, drop the first date column
    df = df.drop('Date', 1)
    #return the dataset
    return df
```